# HP Fortify will not create 'batch' file

Tags: fortify

All,
I am trying to do a static scan on a code repository and the Scan Wizard in HP Fortify SCA and Applications 4.42 will not create the batch file for the scan.

I can add the Project Root, the system then finds all the files, about 18,000-ish.

Then the 2nd screen is shown with the types of files and their counts.  I click the next button.

Then the Dependencies page shows up with the list of Unresolved Classes.  I click the next button.
And the whole window disappears...

Normally, a window with the different language options available would show up and I would be able to pick the version of Java or Pl/Sql that I want to use.  That is not happening.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could get this working?

Thank You,
Larry

Comment: Thank you for the help all.  We determined that there was a folder in the mix that didn't let us make the file.  We removed the folder, there were only a few files in it, and the batch created.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what that folder was called, or what the issue was? I'm having the same problem with the Scan Wizard just mysteriously closing itself and any help would be awesome.

Comment: The directory was labeled 'server' and contained 4 file types: 1. .jpx 2. .xml (which I scan all the time) 3. .class and 4. .java  I didn't look into it any further. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things to try:

**Permissions**

Run the ScanWizard as Administrator (right click -> Run as Administrator).  This will make sure there are no permission issues going on.

**Memory**

This might have to do with memory and the amount of files being looked at.  As the program is running, look at the process to see how much memory is being taken up.  By default ScanWizard JVM is given 300MB to work in.

This might have to be increased.  This is changed in the the `ScanWizard.cmd` file.

Location: `<HPE Fortify Install>/bin/ScanWizard.cmd`

Open this with your favorite text editor and change the `-Xmx300M` command option of this line:

`"%JAVA_CMD%" -Xmx300M -jar "%~dp0\..\Core\lib\ScanWizard-16.10.jar"  %*`

This is a standard JVM option, so keep the values as integers and use M or G (no space for unit)

*Examples:*

- `"%JAVA_CMD%" -Xmx800M -jar "%~dp0\..\Core\lib\ScanWizard-16.10.jar" %*`
- `"%JAVA_CMD%" -Xmx1G -jar "%~dp0\..\Core\lib\ScanWizard-16.10.jar" %*`
- `"%JAVA_CMD%" -Xmx2G -jar "%~dp0\..\Core\lib\ScanWizard-16.10.jar" %*`

**Side Note**

Personally I do not like the ScanWizard, it creates very complex batch files.   I prefer to generate my own batch files calling the sourceanalyzer.exe directly.

Answer (score 0):

Did Fortify Static Code Analyzer (SCA) create an Fortify Project Report (FPR) file? If so, open it in Audit Workbench (AWB) or upload the FPR to the Software Security Center (SSC) to look at the scan errors.

The FPRs will be listed in the "Scan" tab in the SSC.

[image: webgoat java scan errors] 
The scan errors are found in a red dot on the file listing.

[image: webgoat java scan errors popup]

On the other hand, if you are looking at an FPR file in the AWB, open the "Analysis Information" tab

[image: webgoat java in AWB]

and then look below that for the "Warnings" tab.

However I suspect that SCA did not succeed in generating an FPR.

In any case look at your SCA log file for the report of unresolved classes. The log file is at C:\Users_user_\AppData\Local\Fortify\sca6.4\log for scans run with Fortify 4.40. You may have included libraries more than once. Or you successful compilation resulted from the inclusion of libraries from tomcat or other sources that SCA could not find in the code base.

Comment: There was no .fpr created.  The whole system just closed.  No log file nothing.  An 'emergency' ticket was put in with HP and I have yet to hear anything.  Lol

Comment: Sometimes I run .bat files and get an .fpr other times, I don't and no log.

Larry you ever get a response from HP if so please post